# Is it possible to lint only modified part(s) of staged files with the use of lint-staged?

Tags: eslint, prettier, lint-staged

Imagine a source file containing 1000 lines of code (yep, that isn't good, I know).

When you do a slight modification in that file you want your `lint-staged` pre-commit hook to analyze and report errors of only that currently modified staged code part (and related parts, like imports or declarations) instead of printing all errors that it contains.